# Array on Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello i'd like to ask a simple question, here example code

```
<script>
var mycars=["Saab","Volvo","BMW","Honda","BMW","Suzuki","Volvo","Toyota","Saab","Nissan"];
var count=0;
for (i=0;i<mycars.length;i++)
{
document.write(mycars[i] + "<br>");
count++;
}
document.write("Total Data is "+count);
</script>
```

from example above it will output :
Saab
Volvo
BMW
Honda
BMW
Suzuki
Volvo
Toyota
Saab
Nissan
Total Data is 10

how if i want to call each cars just once like BMW,Volvo and Saab it's called twice, and i want it called once then the total data will 7.

how can i give **boolean condition** for this? so it wont called again? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter out the duplicates:

```
mycars = mycars.filter(function(car, index, cars){ return cars.indexOf(car, index + 1) === -1; });
```

After you do this, all but the last instance of each distinct value will be removed from the array. If you need to keep the original array, then use a new variable for the filtered one:

```
var unique_cars = mycars.filter(function(car, index, cars){ return cars.indexOf(car, index + 1) === -1; });
```

Note that you need to shim [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) in older browsers.

Comment: how about if i wont to erase it, but give some condition that some car has been called ?

Comment: maybe if it can used by boolean condition?

Comment: You can create an object to keep track of which cars you've written so far. Before your loop: `var is_car_written = {};`, then in your loop: `if (is_car_written[mycars[i]]) { is_car_written[mycars[i]] = true; document.write(mycars[i] + "<br>"); }'